# How to convert from .SHP to .MAP for mapsforge?

Tags: shapefile, mapsforge

We are using **[mapsforge](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/)**, a Java component for Android.
This component use a proprietary format file (.map) that can be download from OpenStreetMap (OSM).

I need to use .shp maps, so I want to know how can I convert a .shp file into a .map file for mapsforge for Android

Comment: [First hit on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=shapefile+mapsforge): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/WCpBoO1tA8M

Comment: Might that be your post (same name)?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try passing through OSM files.

1. Convert your shp to OSM format with http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shp-to-osm.jar (you have to write a mapping of your columns to OSM tags)
2. Convert this OSM file to Mapsforge with the Map Writer https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter

Answer (score -2):

You can use MapServer Export plugin from from [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/). Just load all your shapefiles to QGIS, set style and other properties, and use Mapserver Export Plugin.

[image]

Comment: This plugin is for MapServer's mapfile, and not mapsforge's .map format